# Japanese movie about young man living in "blind spot"

Tags: identify-this-movie

There is a Japanese movie stuck in my head:

It's about a young man, who delivers flyers (coupons, advertising maybe?) around the city, and he sometimes breaks into flats and houses that he can see are empty (because the flyers are still in the mailbox).

One time he breaks into a house, without realizing a woman is still inside. Eventually they fall in love (I think?), but the husband of the women finds out and he gets arrested (not sure how, but he ends up in jail).

When in jail, the young man practices "shadowplay" skills, where he lingers in peoples blind spots, and therefore can "disappear".  He returns to the house, to live together with the woman, by living in the blindspot of the husband.

This all rather vague, but if someone knows which movie I'm talking about, that would be awesome!

Comment: Is this really a quote, or your own content?

Comment: It's my own content. Not sure how to format it correctly, sorry.

Comment: I don't know who is trying to re-open this question but please stop. THESE QUESTIONS ARE NO LONGER SUPPORTED.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's 3-iron, actually a Korean movie~

> Tae-suk (Jae Hee) is a loner who drives around on his motorbike,
>   taping takeout menus over the keyholes of front doors and breaking
>   into apartments where the menus have not been removed. He lives in
>   those apartments while their owners are away, washing their clothes
>   and mending their broken appliances. When he breaks into one large
>   home, he is unaware that he is being watched by an abused housewife
>   Sun-hwa (Lee Seung-yeon).

Comment: Thanks! That's the one!! Ok so not Japanese, but Korean. Hopefully I didn't insult anyone. Original Title: `Bin-Jip`